# Remote access to a KVM Ubuntu virtual server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization

I've just setup an ubuntu virtual server and everything seems to be working fine. I used KVM to get it working with a bridged network. I've given the virtual server a static ip address on my network.

I don't seem to be able to connect to the virtual machine though from outside my network. If I'm on my own network it all works fine, I can ping the ip and connect to it. The virtual server can ping other machines and sites on the internet.

I changed the port forwarding rules on my router to forward any connections on a specific port to the virtual server ip address thinking that was the problem, but it was still the same.

Is there something I'm missing here which is blocking outside connections to the virtual machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any iptables rules on the dom0 host?  I've seen libvirt set these up by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to get to it locally inside the network, but not outside, perhaps the gateway is not configured for the NIC?

Comment: I've got the correct gateway ip address setup. I can access the outside world fine from the virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using grey ip addresses in your network? It seems that you are using NAT on your gateway to provide access to internet to other machines.

Comment: I basically setup the networking with a bridged network as shown in this guide. It didn't mention anything about grey ip addresses.        http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-11.10

Comment: What is your network subnet?